# S3 : Java SDK : Delete Object tags throws "You must provide the Content-Length HTTP header" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am having trouble deleting tags on existing key.

- SDK Version : compile('software.amazon.awssdk:s3:2.17.2')
- Java version : 1.8

> Error : software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: You must provide the Content-Length HTTP header.

Code snippet:

```
DeleteObjectTaggingRequest deleteObjectTaggingRequest = DeleteObjectTaggingRequest.builder()
                                   .bucket(bucketName)
                                  .key(key)
                                  .build();
        
s3Client.deleteObjectTagging(deleteObjectTaggingRequest);
```

Stack trace:

```
2021-07-22 17:12:46.365 ERROR 13564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: You must provide the Content-Length HTTP header. (Service: S3, Status Code: 411, Request ID: 1626991966461970, Extended Request ID: 12789133)] with root cause

software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: You must provide the Content-Length HTTP header. (Service: S3, Status Code: 411, Request ID:  , Extended Request ID:  )
    at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handleErrorResponse(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:156) ~[aws-xml-protocol-2.17.2.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handleResponse(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:106) ~[aws-xml-protocol-2.17.2.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handle(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:84) ~[aws-xml-protocol-2.17.2.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handle(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:42) ~[aws-xml-protocol-2.17.2.jar:na]
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this with either Java 8 or 11.  Are you modifying the transport layer at all (i.e. changing the HTTP client)?

Comment: No. I am running in Springboot 2.0 version